# What is wrong with my VB 2012 code?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a code that accepts 1 login and then moves it on to Form2, but it won't let me! It says there is build errors:

```
    Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = "User" And TextBox2.Text = "Qf17yu" And TextBox3.Text = "QW56-7456-8UIP" Then MsgBox("Correct login, welcome.", 0 + 64 + "Welcome")
    Else
    MsgBox("Username, password or Secret Key incorrect!", 0 + 64, "Try again")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: _Else_ and _End If_ are underlined with a wavy blue line.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx <-- note that your syntax does not match either one of theirs.

Comment: Also, your first `MsgBox` statement is wrong: `MsgBox("Correct login, welcome.", 0 + 64, "Welcome")` (plus should be comma)

Comment: You don't name controls, you just leave the default names - yuck!!!

Comment: @DonA: +1, and yet it's better than giving them random names instead, like other new programmers do (see other questions on SO). From this code, it's clear that TextBox1 is at least a TextBox. :)

Comment: @Neolisk, right you are!

Answer (score 3):

VB allows you to use two different types of `If` statement, a one-line and a multi-line version, but it does not allow you to mix them.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

You can do:

```
If condition Then dostuff Else dootherstuff End If
```

or you can do:

```
If condition Then
  Dostuff
Else
  Dootherstuff
End If
```

But you cannot mix them in the way you tried to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have `MsgBox` on the same line as your `If`. Add a line after `Then`.

Comment: @user2804232: If Daniel's answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
If TextBox1.Text = "User" And TextBox2.Text = "Qf17yu" And TextBox3.Text = "QW56-7456-8UIP" Then 
MsgBox("Correct login, welcome.", 0 + 64 + "Welcome")
Else
MsgBox("Username, password or Secret Key incorrect!", 0 + 64, "Try again")
End If
```